# How to send geolocation from client to server ? Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loc')

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I got error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loc')

html file :

```
<script>
        // Automatically get the user's location
        if ("geolocation" in navigator) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position)=>{

                const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                
                // creating JSON object to send to server
                const loc = {latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude};

                console.log('\n Location :-',loc,'\n'); //this line successfully shows loc
                
                // I got error as Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loc')
                fetch('/',{

                    method : "POST",
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body : JSON.stringify(loc)
                });
            });
        } else {
            const locationDisplay = document.getElementById('location-display');
            locationDisplay.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not available in your browser.";
        }
</script>
```

javascript file :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{

    const result = req.body.loc;  // accessing location

    console.log(result);          

    res.send('My Location : ',result);  // sending location as response

});

app.listen(500,(err)=>{
    if(err)
        console.error(err);
    console.log('Server is listening of port 500');
})
```

I got location in HTML file but I want to pass that location to server so that I will use for my weather application in future. But when I am trying to pass users location to server using POST, it shows me error.

I have tried to declare `loc` variable outside the block but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because the data you're sending to the server doesn't have the property `loc`. It only has the `latitude` and `longitude` properties as thats what is in your JSON.

`loc` is only a reference tot the object containing those two properties.

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { latitude, longitude } = req.body;
  const result = { latitude, longitude };
  res.send('My Location : ', result);
});
```

I've modified the client JS to log the response from the server.

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (position) => {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                
    const loc = { latitude, longitude };
    console.log('\n Location :-',loc,'\n'); //this line successfully shows loc
    
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/', {
        method : "POST",
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body : JSON.stringify(loc)
      });

      const body = await response.json();
      console.log(body);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }            
  });

} else {
  const locationDisplay = document.getElementById('location-display');
  locationDisplay.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not available in your browser.";
}
```

Comment: What a coincidence it is....I just removed `loc` there and came stackOverflow to answer my question and you also said same thing about removing `loc` variable.  
That I was also playing with that POST method and at one point I just removed `loc` from req.body.loc and I got surprised. My entire code was perfect but due to adding that loc variable I got stuck. 
I wrote req.body.loc because in Post API we fetch the variables from clients like `req.query.id` or `req.body.name` . But I forgot that this is not like that.
thanks for answering my question.